# Opencv detect quadrilateral in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, polygon

I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.0. I am doing a project to **detecting the car license plate**.

I am now checking the number of vertex of the contours. If there are 4 vertex(number of elements in approx), then it is more likely to be a **rectangle**/ **parallelogram**/ **quadrilateral** .

```
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts=sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]

# loop over our contours
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4 and ratio(approx):
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

And I got two quadrilaterals with array.

[image]

However, you can see, there is an **irregular polygon**. This is the array:

```
[[[209 198]]

 [[466  94]]

 [[259 153]]

 [[247   1]]]
```

I am asking for how can I **omitted the irregular quadrilateral.** Thank you

Comment: From the top of my head: Compute the [Convex hull](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656&gsc.tab=0) and compare the original polygon to its convex hull. If they are not similar, it's probably not a licence plate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4606294/user89161 in his comment  [Opencv detect quadrilateral in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942132/opencv-detect-quadrilateral-in-python/37953716#comment63334235_37942132) 
maybe you can add a test on your `approx`, something like:

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(approx,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(approx,hull)

sum_of_defects=0
for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    sum_of_defects=sum_of_defects+d

if sum_of_defects <= threshold:
    print "approx is convex"
else:
    print "approx is not convex"
```

and you have to properly choose `threshold`, I will start with `threshold=3` or something like that. Theoretically `threshold` should be zero.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got a problem that sometimes the `defects` will return NULL

Comment: `    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(approx,hull)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1969: error: (-215) ptnum > 3 in function cv::convexityDefects`

Comment: @CLWONG about the error `ptnum > 3`: it should not happen since you do your test `len(approx) == 4`, or no?

Comment: I have tried with and without `len(approx) == 4`, there are sometimes showing that error

Comment: @CLWONG maybe you have to test the number of point in the `hull` before to call `convexityDefects`, if it is `==3` then you should be pretty sure it is not a quadrilateral?

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you know how many sides your polynomial is supposed to have, for example if you are looking for convex quadrilaterals in an image, then you only need call:

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(approx, returnPoints = False)
```

And then you only need to check that the `len(hull) == num_expected_sides`, in the quadrilateral case:

```
len(cv2.convexHull(approx, returnPoints = False)) == 4
```

Comment: user1270710 I've been trying to develop a kotlin app for weeks that will target a region of interest in wound images. I need the user to use the touch of the device's screen to draw the surroundings of the region of interest, so that the watershed can segment only that region and change the background color to black. I really need to do this and I can't get help from anyone, you can help me with this, please.